# SQL Code Error `Characters found after end of SQL statement`

Tags: sql

I have the following SQL code that I am trying to run in Microsoft Query, but I keep running into the error `Characters found after end of SQL statement`.  I understand this might be happening because of code written after semicolons, but to my knowledge `&gt;` is acceptable.  Is there something else wrong with the code?

```
SELECT `S1`.DATES , `S1`.NAMES , MAX(`LS`.DATES) 
FROM `C:LOCATION`.`Sheet1$` `S1`
LEFT OUTER JOIN `C:\LOCATION`.`LargerSheet$` `LS`
ON `S1`.NAMES = `LS`.NAMES
WHERE (`S1`.DATES - `LS`.DATES) &gt; -3 and (`S1`.DATES - `LS`.DATES) &lt; 3
GROUP BY `S1`.DATES, `S1`.NAMES
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you've posted has been converted to be "HTML safe".

Specifically the `<` (less than) and `>` (greater than) symbols have been replaced by their HTML equivalents `&lt;` and `&gt;`.

Since the semi-colon (`;`) denotes the end of an SQL statement, you are in fact doing exactly what it says -- providing characters after the end of the statement (after the semicolon) that are not another statement on their own.

Replace the `&lt;` and `&gt;` with the actual `<` and `>` characters and try it again.

Comment: No problem, sometimes it just takes a fresh eye. :)